# Invalid `prisma.residency.create()` invocation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, arguments, prisma

When i try to create residency, i have an error like this...

"Argument data.owner.connect of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.

Note: Lines with ? are optional."

```
`
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";

import { prisma } from "../config/prismaConfig.js";

export const createResidency = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    title,
    description,
    price,
    address,
    country,
    city,
    facilities,
    image,
    userEmail,
  } = req.body.data;

  console.log(req.body.data);

  try {
    const residency = await prisma.residency.create({
      data: {
        title,
        description,
        price,
        address,
        country,
        city,
        facilities,
        image,
        owner: { connect: { email: userEmail } },
      },
    });


    res.send({ message: "Residency Created Successfully", residency });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === "P2002") {
      throw new Error("A Residency with address already exist");
    }
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
});
`
```